# How to display multiple markers icon on Gmap3 clustering mod

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I am using gmap3 script to show clustering markers, but i have some questions about it.

First of all my code looks like this.
http://www.ngondesign.com/map/

Gmap3 script has "clusters" option. It allows 3 easy steps to create cluster icons.
For example 0: first icon set, 20: second icon set and 50: third icon set. When build icons, I think gmap capture zoom level and then change icon class. First question is when I click to green cluster icon, how do script get related zoom level?

Second question is when the clusters open, is it possible to show two kinds of icons?
Because, I need two icons end of the maximum zoom level or when the clusters open.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that clusterer is anything like the one at http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html, you should be able to declare a style with one image type and push markers with another image type to the cluster.